How to do fire and forget async call in AWS Lamda Edge function
I am using AWS lamda function as Lamda Edge function for my CloudFront setup. 
This Lamda function needs to call another service to send some metrics data. This operation is non blocking and needs to happen in background without causing any delays in response from lamda.
This works fine when I test Lamda, but when I use Lamda as Lamda Edge function and add it as a trigger to CloudFront the function waits for the request to finish in background before the response is sent back from CloudFront.
Is this normal edge behaviour? How can I make a fire and forget async request from Lamda Edge which will not block the response?
Here is sample code for reference
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
... // some lamda logic here
sendMetrics() 
callback(null, response);
}

function sendMetrics() {
  const options = {
    hostname: 'valid host name'
    path: 'valid path',
    method: 'POST',
    port: 443, 
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  };
  const body = {
       // some data here
    }

    const metricsReq = https.request(options); // async call with no callback
    metricsReq.write(JSON.stringify(body));
    metricsReq.end();
  
}

